# ASP.net ValidationSummary C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two questions that are in the form of radio button lists in C# web application.  These questions have required field validators associated to them and I also have a ValidationSummary at the end of my web control.  When I click on my "Submit" button, the two required field validations appear for each of the questions right next to it and the validationsummary works correctly by stating "Answer the following questions:" and then listing each of the questions that were not selected.  The problem I'm having is when I select one of the two questions, the "Required Field" message disappears next to the question, but not in the ValidationSummary.  How can I get the ValidationSummary to update or refresh when one of the questions in the error messages are selected?  Please let me know if I need to be more specific.  Thanks for your help!

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="Question1" RepeatLayout="Flow" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
     Text="Required" ErrorMessage="Question 1" 
     Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="Question1"
     EnableClientScript="true">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="Question2" RepeatLayout="Flow" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
     Text="Required"  ErrorMessage="Question 2" 
     Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="Question2" 
     EnableClientScript="true">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" 
     HeaderText="Answer the following questions:" 
     DisplayMode="BulletList" 
     EnableClientScript="true"/>

<asp:Button ID="buttonSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
     OnClick="btnSubmit_OnClick"/> 

//Code behind for button
protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.BufferOutput = true;
    Response.Redirect("~/Page.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Please make the question title **meaningful**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the summary doesn't dynamically update by default, but rather only on form submit.

Ordinarily, you could get around this by hooking the client-side onblur event and calling ValidationSummaryOnSubmit(), but it looks like the RadioButtonList doesn't trigger this event when the selected radio button changes.

The next candidate would be the client-side onClick event, but the RadioButtonList control doesn't have an OnClientClick event.

So, the solution which worked for me when I tested it was to hook the client-side onClick event for each ListItem in the RadioButtonList. Like this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="Question1" RepeatLayout="Flow" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes" onClick="ValidationSummaryOnSubmit()"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No" onClick="ValidationSummaryOnSubmit()"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

However, this will get rapidly ugly if you've got a bunch of these that you're going to want to do. Might consider subclassing RadioButtonList and adding a server-side addition of the ListItem onclick hook to each of the child listitems before sending it to the client, and then using your custom version of RadioButtonList instead of the stock version.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response..If I use the onblur would that still be on the clientside?

Comment: Yep, onblur hooks the dom event and executes client-side code.

Comment: I just thought of something...If I add <script language="javascript"> function Validation() { if (Page_ClientValidate()) { return true } } </script> and then in my radiobuttons add onblur="Validation();" do you think that will work?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that'll work.  I pulled the code into a test project and realized that RadioButtonList doesn't generate onblur on the client.  It also doesn't generate onclick.  The individual list items, however, DO generate onclick events.  Bearing this in mind, I updated my answer with a solution that DOES work.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I will try this!  I think I need to add an attribute for the listItem to have an onClick event though right?

Comment: Yes sir, you'll need to add the onClick attribute to each `<asp:ListItem>` tag.  The sample I put in shows you how :)  The ValidationSummaryOnSubmit() call is an asp.net-native method, though, so all that's necessary is the addition of a call to it in the onClick.